# Why does Rails 3 with Mysql2 Gem ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql) return Array not Hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, mysql2

I'm in the process of upgrading an application to Rails 3. I've decided to go with the mysql2 gem. There's some legacy code in the app that makes calls like:

```
results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

In the 2.3.x version, it used

```
results.each_hash do |row|
...
```

But with gem mysql2, results is type `Mysql2::Result`, which has only an `each` method. Checked the docs and they specify results should be a hash keyed on field name. Great!

But in fact, it is an `Array`, not a `Hash`.

When I use the rails console and instantiate my own `Mysql2::Client` and run the query there, the results *are* a `Hash`, which is what I want.

In the rails application, I think it's better to use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection`, since it's been instantiated with options from database.yml.

Note, unfortunately the result does not map to a model, so I can't use that.

What I've done for now is, for example:

```
result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
field_index = result.fields.index("field")
result.each do |row|
  row[field_index]
end
```

Which is ugly as sin.

Does anyone how I can get it to return a Hash instead of Array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want to reuse the `database.yml` configuration, you can do this:

```
config = ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[RAILS_ENV].symbolize_keys
conn = Mysql2::Client.new(config)
conn.query("select * from users").each do |user|
  # user should be a hash
end
```

Comment: That is an improvement over how I did do it, so barring anything "just working", I'll use this. Thank you.

Comment: dan can you help me with my query please?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22997103/find-by-sql-is-not-working-with-prepare-statement

Answer (score 46):

I faced a similar issue a while back and found this to work:

```
result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql) 
result.each(:as => :hash) do |row| 
   row["field"] 
end
```

edit: you could also use the [select_all method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#method-i-select_all) of the connection object that returns a hash

Comment: this is better than selected answer.

Comment: Can you help me please with my query? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22997103/find-by-sql-is-not-working-with-prepare-statement

Answer (score 26):

instead of

```
result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

do

```
results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(sql)
```

And that'll do exactly what you want.  In particular,

```
results.first
```

will be a hash, and so on.

Thanks to @_fx for figuring this out!

For more, see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Mysql2Adapter.html#method-i-exec_query

Comment: I get `undefined method 'exec_query' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter:0x110a0dd48>`

Comment: @dsjoerg thanks for this, I had a surprisingly hard time finding a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select(sql)
```

## table header

```
results.first.keys.each do |key|
 key
end
```

## table data

```
results.each do |result| %>
  result.values.each do |value| %>
    value
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Improving dan's answer, Rails 3.2.8 won't accept RAILS_ENV.

```
    config = ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[Rails.env].symbolize_keys
    conn = Mysql2::Client.new(config)
    conn.query("select * from users").each do |user|
        # user should be a hash
    end
```

Comment: Update @dan's answer if this is what works instead of giving another answer.

Comment: @Ian Done. Sorry for creating a new answer.