# Get ActiveRecord MySQL Query result as a hash, not array

Tags: activerecord, mysql2

When running a mysql query with ActiveRecord with `Class.connection.execute('query here')`, the result is an array, as opposed to a hash in postgres. This is tested with both `mysql` and `mysql2` adapters, even though the default for `mysql2` is to return the query result as a hash.

How can I get `ActiveRecord` to change the configuration options on the connection to return query results as a hash? Can I just not use `ActiveRecord` for this and I should use the raw `mysql2` client?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does Rails 3 with Mysql2 Gem ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql) return Array not Hash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760100/why-does-rails-3-with-mysql2-gem-activerecordbase-connection-executesql-retu)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I had a similar problem and I found the solution on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760100/why-does-rails-3-with-mysql2-gem-activerecordbase-connection-executesql-retu):

You can do `data = Class.connection.exec_query('query here')` to get an [ActiveRecord::Result](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Result.html)

Then, you can do `data.first` for a hash, or use any of the other methods mentioned in the docs.

Comment: Thanks, it's `exec_query` that do the trick, I was testing with `execute`

Comment: @244an Glad this is still helpful! :)